# Removing a char from String, what's a more efficient way to do this?

Tags: python, string, performance, python-2.7

I'm currently studying Python 2.7 from an online course. One of the problems is I have to remove a char from a string based from a list of chars.

What I did was:

```
def getAvailableLetters(letters):

    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    reduced_alphabet = ''

    for char in alphabet:
        if char not in lettersGuessed:
            reduced_alphabet += char

    return reduced_alphabet
```

I've learned that there's no such thing as a string method to directly remove a char from a string as they are immutable, so I came up with this. I've successfully submitted a correct answer, but I'm not quite satisfied with it as I feel like there's a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Because the answers there apply directly to your problem; replace `string.punctuation` with (a string created from) `lettersGuessed`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fastest way would be to use `str.translate` here:

```
>>> lettersGuessed = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> 'wedqwdasdasccdshjasdcas'.translate(None, ''.join(lettersGuessed))
'wedqwdsdsdshjsds'
```

if `lettersGuessed` is already a string then remove the `''.join` call.

Timing results compared to `str.join` and `filter`, taken from @thefourtheye's solution:

```
def getAvailableLetters2(lettersGuessed):
    return string.ascii_lowercase.translate(None, lettersGuessed)

from timeit import timeit
print 'filter-->', timeit("getAvailableLetters('Welcome')", setup="from __main__ import getAvailableLetters")
print '.join-->', timeit("getAvailableLetters1('Welcome')",setup="from __main__ import getAvailableLetters1")
print 'trans-->', timeit("getAvailableLetters2('Welcome')",setup="from __main__ import getAvailableLetters2")
```

**Output:**

```
filter--> 6.49355100548
.join--> 4.02496357229
trans--> 0.69938109531
```

Comment: +1 I am wondering why `translate` is the fastest. Amazing.

Comment: I too often forget about `translate` and how it is great for *removing* characters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could you please tell me why `translate` is faster? How is it implemented internally?

Comment: @thefourtheye http://stackoverflow.com/a/266162/846892

Comment: @thefourtheye: C string magic; lookup tables in C operating directly on the string bytes.

Comment: I already upvoted. Somebody please upvote this answer. This has to be at the top.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [This](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0f48843652b1/Objects/bytesobject.c#l1481) could be that function?

Comment: @hcwhsa, lost in speed) you're machine is faster too, my results were ~8.6, ~5.6, ~0.9 secs :)

Comment: @thefourtheye: That is that function, for the Python 3 `bytes` type. The `str` (unicode) type also has one, albeit slightly different in implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this, to filter out the characters which are in `lettersGuessed`

```
import string
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    return "".join([char for char in string.ascii_lowercase if char not in lettersGuessed])

print getAvailableLetters("Welcome")
```

**Output**

```
abdfghijknpqrstuvwxyz
```

Alternatively, you can use [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function like this

```
import string
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    return filter(lambda x: x not in lettersGuessed, string.ascii_lowercase)

print getAvailableLetters("Welcome")
```

**Output**

```
abdfghijknpqrstuvwxyz
```

**Edit:** Performance comparison

```
import string
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    return filter(lambda x: x not in lettersGuessed, string.ascii_lowercase)

def getAvailableLetters1(lettersGuessed):
    return "".join([char for char in string.ascii_lowercase if char not in lettersGuessed])

from timeit import timeit
print timeit("getAvailableLetters('Welcome')", setup="from __main__ import getAvailableLetters")
print timeit("getAvailableLetters1('Welcome')",setup="from __main__ import getAvailableLetters1")
```

**Output on my machine**

```
3.02976298332
2.00461006165
```

It shows that, `list comprehension` method beats `filter` method.

Comment: I suspect it's the `lambda` that kills the `filter()` performance here. For `filter(str.isupper, 'abcABC')` vs. `''.join([c for c in 'abcABC' if c.isupper()])`, `filter()` wins.

Comment: And `str.translate` beats both of them.

Comment: Using `functools.partial(operator.contains, lettersGuessed)` makes the filter faster than the `''.join()`. But `str.translate` still wins.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is to use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to turn a sequence of characters into a new string:

```
return ''.join([char for char in string.ascii_lowercase if char not in lettersGuessed])
```

This avoids creating a new string object every iteration of the loop; instead, the new string is created *once*.